# Hide icons from Gnome launcher applications page in Fedora 26

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

We are trying to hide application icons from the Gnome launcher. Note, this is not the Dash panel on the left, this is when you click the Applications icon in the dash panel and it shows you all the applications.

I have tried the following (with a reboot in between each (wayland won't allow restarting of gnome)):

- add `NoDisplay=True` to the end of `/usr/share/applications/app-name.desktop`
- add `Hidden=True` to the end of `/usr/share/applications/app-name.desktop`
- copied those `.desktop` files to `~/.local/share/applications`
- disabled Search in gnome-control-center
- `mv /usr/share/applications/*.desktop /another/directory` (system won't boot)
- installed and tried alacarte

The problem with moving the desktop items is that the system relies on these files during boot. Also, the gnome-control-center relies on the sub-component `*.desktop` items existing in `/usr/share/applications`. I am assuming this has something to do with the new Wayland display system replacing X11, but am not sure. Thanks.

Comment: According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries `NoDisplay=True` in `~/.local/share/applications` should do the that. If it does not, it might be a bug. I don't have Fedora 26 at hand now, but I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: I just tried it again and no luck.

Answer (score 5):

The **True** should be lowercase. Adding this line works for me:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

Should work for both `~/.local/share/applications/app-name.desktop` and `/usr/share/applications/app-name.desktop`.

Also, you can hide the entry only for a specific desktop by adding `NotShowIn=desktop-name`, as mentioned in the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries#Hide_desktop_entries).

Comment: This unfortunably also hides it for the Open With Other Application menu. I only want to hide one application from search or give it a lower search priority.